# Cleveref fails to pick up the footnote number when using svmono 5.6 class

Tags: footnotes, theorems, cleveref, sv-classes

Consider the following input:

```
\documentclass{svmono}%%% Version 5.6 from https://www.springer.com/gp/authors-editors/book-authors-editors/resources-guidelines/book-manuscript-guidelines/manuscript-preparation/5636
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\begin{document}
\begin{theorem}\label[theorem]{exmp:myExample}
  Text.\footnote{\label{ftnt:myFootnoteOne}First footnote.}
  Text.\footnote{\label[footnote]{ftnt:myFootnoteTwo}Second footnote.}
  Text.\footnote{\label{ftnt:myFootnoteThree}Third footnote.}
  Text.\footnote{\label[footnote]{ftnt:myFootnoteFour}Fourth footnote.}
\end{theorem}
References to footnotes 3 and 4 with \texttt{\textbackslash cref}: \cref{ftnt:myFootnoteThree}, \cref{ftnt:myFootnoteFour}.\\
References to footnotes 3 and 4 with \texttt{\textbackslash ref}: \ref{ftnt:myFootnoteThree}, \ref{ftnt:myFootnoteFour}.
\end{document}
```

Feeding this to either of `pdflatex`, `xelatex`, or `lualatex` results in a failure of `\cref` to determine and print the footnote numbers:

[image: output]

As we see, `\cref` prints the number of the enclosing environment (here, `theorem`) instead.

How to fix this?  I informed the author of `cleveref`, but my attempts to reach out to Springer ended nowhere (an automatic answer emerged saying *texhelp [at] springer [dot] com* and *texhelp [at] springer [dot] de* are dead).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

svmono overwrites at begin document the footnote definition of cleveref. So you should overwrite it again.

```
\documentclass{svmono}%%% Version 5.6 from https://www.springer.com/gp/authors-editors/book-authors-editors/resources-guidelines/book-manuscript-guidelines/manuscript-preparation/5636
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
\let\cref@old@makefntext\@makefntext%
\long\def\@makefntext{%
  \cref@constructprefix{footnote}{\cref@result}%
  \protected@edef\cref@currentlabel{%
    [footnote][\arabic{footnote}][\cref@result]%
    \p@footnote\@thefnmark}%
  \cref@old@makefntext}%
 } 
\makeatother 
\begin{document}
\begin{theorem}\label[theorem]{exmp:myExample}
  Text.\footnote{\label{ftnt:myFootnoteOne}First footnote.}
  Text.\footnote{\label[footnote]{ftnt:myFootnoteTwo}Second footnote.}
  Text.\footnote{\label{ftnt:myFootnoteThree}Third footnote.}
  Text.\footnote{\label[footnote]{ftnt:myFootnoteFour}Fourth footnote.}
\end{theorem}
References to footnotes 3 and 4 with \texttt{\textbackslash cref}: \cref{ftnt:myFootnoteThree}, \cref{ftnt:myFootnoteFour}.\\
References to footnotes 3 and 4 with \texttt{\textbackslash ref}: \ref{ftnt:myFootnoteThree}, \ref{ftnt:myFootnoteFour}.
\end{document}
```